# Array keep empty after push object from forEach

Tags: node.js, express

Need Help, I have problem  Array Keep Empty After pushing object from forEach, do I miss something ? here's the code :

```
const allStatus = [];
    result.forEach(async (element) => {
      const count = await BpCandidate.count({
        where: {
          applicationStatusId: element.id
        },
        raw: true,
      });
      })  
      record = {
        id: element.id,
        name: element.name,
        code: element.code,
        description: element.description,
        total: count
      };
      allStatus.push(record);
    });
    console.log(allStatus);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get the output for result?

Comment: yes I Get the output for result @RajaShekar, but for the allStatus it's  empty array only []

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: `result.forEach` doesn't wait for the async functions to resolve.

Comment: Also bluebird provides useful array helpers like [.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

Comment: Thanks for help @Matt im using ```for … of```` it's now working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `for...of` is working for you, but can see an improvement here if you use `Promise.all`

```js
const allStatus = await Promise.all(result.map(async (element) => {
  const count = await BpCandidate.count({
    where: {
      applicationStatusId: element.id
    },
    raw: true,
  });
  return  {
    id: element.id,
    name: element.name,
    code: element.code,
    description: element.description,
    total: count
  };
}))
```

Comment: @NelvanBalthazar My bad, forgot to update to use `map` instead of `forEach`. Please check my updated comment.

Answer (score 1):

first you need to define `element` variable in outer scope of foreach part to get the desired result, here is the helper code snippet:

```
    const allStatus = [];
    result.forEach(async (element) => {
      const count = await BpCandidate.count({
        where: {
          applicationStatusId: element.id
        },
        raw: true,
      });
      record = {
        id: element.id,
        name: element.name,
        code: element.code,
        description: element.description,
        total: count
      };
      allStatus.push(record);
      })  
    });
    console.log(allStatus);
```

Answer (score 1):

for each doesn't perform async task and doesn't resolve promises.
Use for of or Promise.All the loop iterations.

```
const allStatus = [];
for(let element of result) {
  const count = await BpCandidate.count({
    where: {
      applicationStatusId: element.id
    },
    raw: true,
  });
  })  
  record = {
    id: element.id,
    name: element.name,
    code: element.code,
    description: element.description,
    total: count
  };
  allStatus.push(record);
});
console.log(allStatus);
```