# How to access outer variable in forEach?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the code snippet. I want to access imagePath array inside for each.

...

```
const imagePath=[];
             
req.files.images.forEach(async (image) => {
   let extName = path.extname(image.name);
   var dest = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'images', 'items');
   var imgPath = await saveFile(image, dest, itemName, extName);
   imagePath.push(imgPath); // this line
})
```

...

Comment: yes, that's how you do it - of course, there's no guarantee the order will be maintained since you have asynchronous code inside the forEach

Comment: it's not working

Comment: "it's not working" is not useful ... what is happening that is different to what you expect? your code will "work" as is, no errors in the code itself .... so ... what's the *actual* problem? - let me guess, on the very next line, you `console.log(imagePath)` and it's empty? That would be due to asynchrony inside the forEach callback

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I checked other vaiable. I can access them.

Comment: see, you should present the code you have an issue with :p

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+async+push+in+foreach+array+empty) of [Array keep empty after push object from forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62274923/4642212).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Normally, `imagePath` is easily accessible in your `forEach` loop.

However, your `forEach` callback is asynchronous. If you do a `console.log(imagePath)` right after the `forEach` loop, you will get an empty array.

A simple workaround would be to use a [`for`…`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

Comment: This answer doesn’t explain how a `for`…`in` loop helps with asynchronicity at all. You can step in the same traps as with the `forEach` call, and you can make the code work without `for`…`in`.